# mysql multiple tables move data (insert and delete)

Tags: mysql

I have need to perform multiple table move and i amdoing it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fiscal_rad_test` (`objectid`, `dan`, `smena`, `racun`, `owner`, `konobar`, `sto`, `tip`, `konto`, `datum`, `vreme`, `tiprobe`, `roba`, `naziv`, `kolicina`, `cena`, `ukupno`, `nabavna`, `stanje`, `porez`, `kategorija`)
    SELECT `objectid`,
           `dan`,
           `smena`,
           `racun`,
           `owner`,
           `konobar`,
           `sto`,
           `tip`,
           `konto`,
           `datum`,
           `vreme`,
           `tiprobe`,
           `roba`,
           `naziv`,
           `kolicina`,
           `cena`,
           `ukupno`,
           `nabavna`,
           `stanje`,
           `porez`,
           `kategorija`
    FROM `fiscal_rad_temp_test`
    WHERE objectid = '$object'");   
$transacitionresult = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fiscal_transactions` (`objectid`, `dan`, `smena`, `owner`, `konobar`, `sto`, `tip`, `konto`, `datum`, `vreme`, `racun`, `data`, `ukupno`)
    SELECT `objectid`,
           `dan`,
           `smena`,
           `owner`,
           `konobar`,
           `sto`,
           `tip`,
           `konto`,
           `datum`,
           `vreme`,
           `racun`,
           `data`,
           `ukupno`
    FROM `fiscal_transactions_temp`
    WHERE objectid = '$object'");
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `fiscal_transactions_temp` WHERE objectid = '$object'");
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `fiscal_rad_temp_test` WHERE objectid = '$object'");
```

Is it better and more reliable way to do this?
Can i excepct something wrong, perhaps some rows not deleted with this approach?

Comment: The only potential problem is if there's an interruption between the insert and delete. If you're using InnoDB you could use transactions to make it safer.

Comment: Did you select all fields in your insert selection ? If yes, then you can replace all of them by an * like : SELECT * FROM ... this way, your query will be clearer. I'm agree with @Barmar. Take a look at this tutorial to make transaction : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: No i am actually selecting all but ID with autoincreament field in both tables, in order to get autoincreament id field in both tables automaticly